# Entity Framework Provider for Web Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-services

Suppose you have a C# application using Entity Framework to access a database. The data models (entities) are used across all layers up to the UI.

Now suppose there is a new requirement which says that your application has to be more service-oriented. I.e. the business logic and database run on a server the UI client connects to and exchanges data with.

In order to reduce the amount of work required for this change, would it be possible to [implement a data provider for the Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee789835(v=vs.100).aspx) which targets a web service instead of a database? To keep things simple the web service could pass client queries and entity changes on to an entity framework context running on the server.

Does this make sense at all? Is it possible in any way?

Comment: _"Is it possible"_ - yes, but writing a how-to would be a bit too broad. You could have solved this using a Repository pattern that is datasource-agnostic, so you could've swapped the Entity Framework datasource for a webservice datasource.

Comment: I don't recommend implementing a EF data provider for this task. What you need is just a good layered architecture like i.e.: onion architecture http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/